# How to get the version number of the file using BOX-SDK?

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

BoxFileVersion CLASS doesn't seem to have a method to get the name of the version ("V1", "V2" etc).

I can see that BoxFile.Info has a getVersionNumber() method but this just returns a null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BoxFile.Info.getVersionNumber()` will give you the version number, but this attribute is not populated by default - it's listed in italics in [Box API docs](https://docs.box.com/v2.0/reference#file-object).

Optional attributes need to be requested explicitly, e.g. by calling `BoxFile.getInfo(fields)` with "version_number" in `fields` array.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer

Comment: THANKS! I was trying to find out how to get the file version in the output of the /folders/[folderid]/items endpoint. "version_number" does not appear anywhere that I could find in the documentation, but it works in the fields parameter for that call too.